# how to resolve : index out of bound C# arrays, streams

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream

i get index out of bound on line :   `stream.Read(fileBytes[i], 0, fileBytes[i].Length);`
any help would be appreciated . thanks :)

```cs
string[] path = new string[15];
byte[][] fileBytes = new byte[10][];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

 path[i] = @ "C:\Users\t-chkum\Desktop\InputFiles\1MB\" + i + ".txt ";

 // readind data/* 
 FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path[i]);
 fileBytes[i] = new byte[stream.Length];

 //  Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
 stream.Read(fileBytes[i], 0, fileBytes[i].Length);
 stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: You JUST asked that question a little bit ago... did you not read the comments? [Reference to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179182/index-out-of-bound-c-sharp-arrays)

Comment: There was someting wrong with that code. Thats why i asked again after correcting it

Comment: If there's something wrong with the code in your question, [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62179182/edit). Do not repeat your question.

Comment: okay will take care of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating from `i`=`1` to `10` inclusive. But, the size of the array is `10` i.e. the index goes from `0` to `9`. So, either start `i` from `0`, or index using `i-1`. Also, use `try-catch`. This would help you to debug better.

Otherwise, the code is working fine for me.

Comment: Link to array doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: Thankyou so much :)